# Merge multiple date columns and drop the not needed date columns

Tags: pandas, date

I have the following dataframe:

```
pd.Dataframe({'Col1': {0: '04/01/2021',
  1: '04/01/2021',
  2: '04/01/2021',
  3: '04/01/2021',
  4: '04/01/2021',
  5: '05/01/2021',
  6: '05/01/2021',
  7: '05/01/2021',
  8: '06/01/2021',
  9: '06/01/2021',
  10: '06/01/2021',
  11: '06/01/2021',
  12: '06/01/2021',
  13: '06/01/2021',
  14: '06/01/2021',
  15: '06/01/2021',
  16: '07/01/2021',
  17: '07/01/2021',
  18: '07/01/2021',
  19: '07/01/2021',
  20: '07/01/2021',
  21: '07/01/2021',
  22: '07/01/2021',
  23: '08/01/2021',
  24: '08/01/2021',
  25: '08/01/2021',
  26: '08/01/2021',
  27: '08/01/2021',
  28: '08/01/2021',
  29: '08/01/2021',
  30: '08/01/2021',
  31: '08/01/2021',
  32: '08/01/2021',
  33: '08/01/2021',
  34: '08/01/2021',
  35: '08/01/2021',
  36: '08/01/2021',
  37: '08/01/2021',
  38: '11/01/2021',
  39: '11/01/2021',
  40: '11/01/2021',
  41: '11/01/2021',
  42: '11/01/2021',
  43: '11/01/2021',
  44: '11/01/2021',
  45: '11/01/2021',
  46: '11/01/2021',
  47: '11/01/2021',
  48: '11/01/2021',
  49: '11/01/2021',
  50: '11/01/2021',
  51: '11/01/2021',
  52: '11/01/2021',
  53: '11/01/2021',
  54: '12/01/2021',
  55: '12/01/2021',
  56: '12/01/2021',
  57: '12/01/2021',
  58: '12/01/2021',
  59: '12/01/2021',
  60: '12/01/2021',
  61: '12/01/2021',
  62: '12/01/2021',
  63: '12/01/2021',
  64: '12/01/2021',
  65: '12/01/2021',
  66: '12/01/2021',
  67: '12/01/2021',
  68: '12/01/2021',
  69: '12/01/2021',
  70: '12/01/2021',
  71: '13/01/2021',
  72: '13/01/2021',
  73: '13/01/2021',
  74: '13/01/2021',
  75: '13/01/2021',
  76: '13/01/2021',
  77: '13/01/2021',
  78: '13/01/2021',
  79: '13/01/2021',
  80: '13/01/2021',
  81: '13/01/2021',
  82: '14/01/2021',
  83: '14/01/2021',
  84: '14/01/2021',
  85: '14/01/2021',
  86: '14/01/2021',
  87: '14/01/2021',
  88: '14/01/2021',
  89: '14/01/2021',
  90: '14/01/2021',
  91: '14/01/2021',
  92: '14/01/2021',
  93: '14/01/2021',
  94: '14/01/2021',
  95: '14/01/2021',
  96: '14/01/2021',
  97: '14/01/2021',
  98: '14/01/2021',
  99: '14/01/2021',
  100: '15/01/2021',
  101: '15/01/2021',
  102: '15/01/2021',
  103: '15/01/2021',
  104: '15/01/2021',
  105: '15/01/2021',
  106: nan,
  107: nan},
 'Col2': {0: 17.0,
  1: 93.0,
  2: 76.0,
  3: 93.0,
  4: 72.0,
  5: 52.0,
  6: 97.0,
  7: 78.0,
  8: 38.0,
  9: 42.0,
  10: 40.0,
  11: 25.0,
  12: 18.0,
  13: 23.0,
  14: 69.0,
  15: 12.0,
  16: 5.0,
  17: 82.0,
  18: 92.0,
  19: 98.0,
  20: 85.0,
  21: 39.0,
  22: 37.0,
  23: 84.0,
  24: 79.0,
  25: 40.0,
  26: 46.0,
  27: 92.0,
  28: 53.0,
  29: 92.0,
  30: 60.0,
  31: 36.0,
  32: 19.0,
  33: 100.0,
  34: 36.0,
  35: 39.0,
  36: 48.0,
  37: 59.0,
  38: 78.0,
  39: 30.0,
  40: 22.0,
  41: 41.0,
  42: 71.0,
  43: 73.0,
  44: 34.0,
  45: 91.0,
  46: 47.0,
  47: 15.0,
  48: 75.0,
  49: 2.0,
  50: 82.0,
  51: 68.0,
  52: 46.0,
  53: 85.0,
  54: 100.0,
  55: 93.0,
  56: 13.0,
  57: 12.0,
  58: 14.0,
  59: 35.0,
  60: 27.0,
  61: 75.0,
  62: 49.0,
  63: 100.0,
  64: 98.0,
  65: 19.0,
  66: 50.0,
  67: 88.0,
  68: 85.0,
  69: 47.0,
  70: 91.0,
  71: 24.0,
  72: 45.0,
  73: 86.0,
  74: 80.0,
  75: 70.0,
  76: 73.0,
  77: 47.0,
  78: 65.0,
  79: 19.0,
  80: 30.0,
  81: 43.0,
  82: 73.0,
  83: 10.0,
  84: 57.0,
  85: 3.0,
  86: 56.0,
  87: 76.0,
  88: 51.0,
  89: 65.0,
  90: 94.0,
  91: 23.0,
  92: 78.0,
  93: 24.0,
  94: 94.0,
  95: 74.0,
  96: 95.0,
  97: 11.0,
  98: 1.0,
  99: 90.0,
  100: 78.0,
  101: 20.0,
  102: 11.0,
  103: 69.0,
  104: 75.0,
  105: 33.0,
  106: nan,
  107: nan},
 'Col3': {0: '06/01/2021',
  1: '06/01/2021',
  2: '06/01/2021',
  3: '06/01/2021',
  4: '06/01/2021',
  5: '06/01/2021',
  6: '06/01/2021',
  7: '07/01/2021',
  8: '07/01/2021',
  9: '07/01/2021',
  10: '07/01/2021',
  11: '07/01/2021',
  12: '07/01/2021',
  13: '07/01/2021',
  14: '08/01/2021',
  15: '11/01/2021',
  16: '11/01/2021',
  17: '11/01/2021',
  18: '11/01/2021',
  19: '11/01/2021',
  20: '11/01/2021',
  21: '11/01/2021',
  22: '11/01/2021',
  23: '11/01/2021',
  24: '12/01/2021',
  25: '12/01/2021',
  26: '12/01/2021',
  27: '12/01/2021',
  28: '12/01/2021',
  29: '12/01/2021',
  30: '12/01/2021',
  31: '12/01/2021',
  32: '12/01/2021',
  33: '12/01/2021',
  34: '12/01/2021',
  35: '12/01/2021',
  36: '12/01/2021',
  37: '12/01/2021',
  38: '12/01/2021',
  39: '12/01/2021',
  40: '12/01/2021',
  41: '13/01/2021',
  42: '13/01/2021',
  43: '13/01/2021',
  44: '13/01/2021',
  45: '06/01/2021',
  46: '07/01/2021',
  47: '07/01/2021',
  48: '07/01/2021',
  49: '07/01/2021',
  50: '07/01/2021',
  51: '07/01/2021',
  52: '07/01/2021',
  53: '08/01/2021',
  54: '08/01/2021',
  55: '08/01/2021',
  56: '08/01/2021',
  57: '08/01/2021',
  58: '08/01/2021',
  59: '08/01/2021',
  60: '08/01/2021',
  61: '08/01/2021',
  62: '08/01/2021',
  63: '08/01/2021',
  64: '08/01/2021',
  65: '08/01/2021',
  66: '08/01/2021',
  67: '08/01/2021',
  68: '06/01/2021',
  69: '06/01/2021',
  70: '07/01/2021',
  71: '07/01/2021',
  72: '07/01/2021',
  73: '07/01/2021',
  74: '07/01/2021',
  75: '07/01/2021',
  76: '07/01/2021',
  77: '08/01/2021',
  78: '08/01/2021',
  79: '08/01/2021',
  80: '08/01/2021',
  81: '08/01/2021',
  82: '08/01/2021',
  83: '08/01/2021',
  84: '08/01/2021',
  85: '08/01/2021',
  86: '08/01/2021',
  87: '08/01/2021',
  88: '08/01/2021',
  89: nan,
  90: nan,
  91: nan,
  92: nan,
  93: nan,
  94: nan,
  95: nan,
  96: nan,
  97: nan,
  98: nan,
  99: nan,
  100: nan,
  101: nan,
  102: nan,
  103: nan,
  104: nan,
  105: nan,
  106: nan,
  107: nan},
 'Col4': {0: 40.0,
  1: 45.0,
  2: 63.0,
  3: 10.0,
  4: 52.0,
  5: 71.0,
  6: 24.0,
  7: 44.0,
  8: 10.0,
  9: 64.0,
  10: 43.0,
  11: 5.0,
  12: 34.0,
  13: 63.0,
  14: 86.0,
  15: 81.0,
  16: 81.0,
  17: 4.0,
  18: 25.0,
  19: 68.0,
  20: 48.0,
  21: 68.0,
  22: 33.0,
  23: 32.0,
  24: 70.0,
  25: 10.0,
  26: 11.0,
  27: 70.0,
  28: 44.0,
  29: 75.0,
  30: 80.0,
  31: 52.0,
  32: 67.0,
  33: 27.0,
  34: 38.0,
  35: 49.0,
  36: 26.0,
  37: 23.0,
  38: 95.0,
  39: 9.0,
  40: 29.0,
  41: 47.0,
  42: 19.0,
  43: 21.0,
  44: 88.0,
  45: 81.0,
  46: 95.0,
  47: 62.0,
  48: 32.0,
  49: 75.0,
  50: 82.0,
  51: 39.0,
  52: 43.0,
  53: 55.0,
  54: 70.0,
  55: 50.0,
  56: 82.0,
  57: 5.0,
  58: 2.0,
  59: 89.0,
  60: 100.0,
  61: 43.0,
  62: 61.0,
  63: 43.0,
  64: 68.0,
  65: 41.0,
  66: 76.0,
  67: 49.0,
  68: 12.0,
  69: 36.0,
  70: 13.0,
  71: 54.0,
  72: 64.0,
  73: 66.0,
  74: 19.0,
  75: 45.0,
  76: 66.0,
  77: 51.0,
  78: 47.0,
  79: 92.0,
  80: 90.0,
  81: 79.0,
  82: 69.0,
  83: 67.0,
  84: 72.0,
  85: 13.0,
  86: 50.0,
  87: 12.0,
  88: 69.0,
  89: nan,
  90: nan,
  91: nan,
  92: nan,
  93: nan,
  94: nan,
  95: nan,
  96: nan,
  97: nan,
  98: nan,
  99: nan,
  100: nan,
  101: nan,
  102: nan,
  103: nan,
  104: nan,
  105: nan,
  106: nan,
  107: nan},
 'Col5': {0: '12/01/2021',
  1: '12/01/2021',
  2: '12/01/2021',
  3: '12/01/2021',
  4: '12/01/2021',
  5: '12/01/2021',
  6: '12/01/2021',
  7: '12/01/2021',
  8: '12/01/2021',
  9: '13/01/2021',
  10: '13/01/2021',
  11: '13/01/2021',
  12: '13/01/2021',
  13: '13/01/2021',
  14: '13/01/2021',
  15: '13/01/2021',
  16: '13/01/2021',
  17: '13/01/2021',
  18: '13/01/2021',
  19: '13/01/2021',
  20: '14/01/2021',
  21: '14/01/2021',
  22: '14/01/2021',
  23: '14/01/2021',
  24: '14/01/2021',
  25: '14/01/2021',
  26: '14/01/2021',
  27: '14/01/2021',
  28: '14/01/2021',
  29: '14/01/2021',
  30: '14/01/2021',
  31: '14/01/2021',
  32: '14/01/2021',
  33: '14/01/2021',
  34: '14/01/2021',
  35: '14/01/2021',
  36: '14/01/2021',
  37: '14/01/2021',
  38: '15/01/2021',
  39: '15/01/2021',
  40: '15/01/2021',
  41: '15/01/2021',
  42: '15/01/2021',
  43: '15/01/2021',
  44: nan,
  45: nan,
  46: nan,
  47: nan,
  48: nan,
  49: nan,
  50: nan,
  51: nan,
  52: nan,
  53: nan,
  54: nan,
  55: nan,
  56: nan,
  57: nan,
  58: nan,
  59: nan,
  60: nan,
  61: nan,
  62: nan,
  63: nan,
  64: nan,
  65: nan,
  66: nan,
  67: nan,
  68: nan,
  69: nan,
  70: nan,
  71: nan,
  72: nan,
  73: nan,
  74: nan,
  75: nan,
  76: nan,
  77: nan,
  78: nan,
  79: nan,
  80: nan,
  81: nan,
  82: nan,
  83: nan,
  84: nan,
  85: nan,
  86: nan,
  87: nan,
  88: nan,
  89: nan,
  90: nan,
  91: nan,
  92: nan,
  93: nan,
  94: nan,
  95: nan,
  96: nan,
  97: nan,
  98: nan,
  99: nan,
  100: nan,
  101: nan,
  102: nan,
  103: nan,
  104: nan,
  105: nan,
  106: nan,
  107: nan},
 'Col6': {0: 466.0,
  1: 421.0,
  2: 497.0,
  3: 487.0,
  4: 426.0,
  5: 421.0,
  6: 408.0,
  7: 461.0,
  8: 470.0,
  9: 419.0,
  10: 492.0,
  11: 406.0,
  12: 424.0,
  13: 496.0,
  14: 475.0,
  15: 431.0,
  16: 457.0,
  17: 449.0,
  18: 466.0,
  19: 458.0,
  20: 491.0,
  21: 484.0,
  22: 404.0,
  23: 474.0,
  24: 459.0,
  25: 421.0,
  26: 461.0,
  27: 484.0,
  28: 493.0,
  29: 496.0,
  30: 439.0,
  31: 465.0,
  32: 414.0,
  33: 449.0,
  34: 490.0,
  35: 416.0,
  36: 432.0,
  37: 472.0,
  38: 465.0,
  39: 428.0,
  40: 422.0,
  41: 414.0,
  42: 471.0,
  43: 450.0,
  44: nan,
  45: nan,
  46: nan,
  47: nan,
  48: nan,
  49: nan,
  50: nan,
  51: nan,
  52: nan,
  53: nan,
  54: nan,
  55: nan,
  56: nan,
  57: nan,
  58: nan,
  59: nan,
  60: nan,
  61: nan,
  62: nan,
  63: nan,
  64: nan,
  65: nan,
  66: nan,
  67: nan,
  68: nan,
  69: nan,
  70: nan,
  71: nan,
  72: nan,
  73: nan,
  74: nan,
  75: nan,
  76: nan,
  77: nan,
  78: nan,
  79: nan,
  80: nan,
  81: nan,
  82: nan,
  83: nan,
  84: nan,
  85: nan,
  86: nan,
  87: nan,
  88: nan,
  89: nan,
  90: nan,
  91: nan,
  92: nan,
  93: nan,
  94: nan,
  95: nan,
  96: nan,
  97: nan,
  98: nan,
  99: nan,
  100: nan,
  101: nan,
  102: nan,
  103: nan,
  104: nan,
  105: nan,
  106: nan,
  107: nan}})
```

Col1 is the master data column. I need to merge Col3 and Col5 dates, to the master column. The final dataframe should be the merging of Col3 and Col5, to Col1 (master date field), and the values of all those dates are maintained.

It will be ideal to automatically drop the date fields Col3 and Col5, and only the value fields maintained at the end.

Col1 (date) maps with values in Col2, Col3 (date) maps with values in Col4 and Col5 (date) maps with values in Col6.

Based on this, is there a simple Pandas code that can be applied to perform the above intended operation ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with "merge" in this case. Your dates are not unique so I imagine you want to concatenate Col3/4 and Col5/6 to Col1/2 (renaming Col3 and Col5 in the process):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': {0: '04/01/2021',
 ...
  107: nan}})

df_12 = df[["Col1", "Col2"]].dropna()
df_34 = df[["Col3", "Col4"]].dropna()
df_34.columns = ["Col1", "Col4"]
df_56 = df[["Col5", "Col6"]].dropna()
df_56.columns = ["Col1", "Col6"]

df_new = pd.concat([df_12, df_34, df_56], ignore_index=True)
print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
           Col1  Col2  Col4   Col6
0    04/01/2021  17.0   NaN    NaN
1    04/01/2021  93.0   NaN    NaN
2    04/01/2021  76.0   NaN    NaN
3    04/01/2021  93.0   NaN    NaN
4    04/01/2021  72.0   NaN    NaN
..          ...   ...   ...    ...
234  15/01/2021   NaN   NaN  428.0
235  15/01/2021   NaN   NaN  422.0
236  15/01/2021   NaN   NaN  414.0
237  15/01/2021   NaN   NaN  471.0
238  15/01/2021   NaN   NaN  450.0
```